# how to get lost mailbox username

Tags: mozilla

A few weeks ago i registered a new "temporary" gmail mailbox...unfortunatelly (and 'coz im so forgetful) i forgot my username.

Anyone could suggest me a program or plugin for mozilla which i can list all information what ever typed in an inout field in my browser?

Than you..

Comment: dont believe there is such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox the "Form History Control" https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/12021/ allows you to see what you've typed into forms. If you haven't cleared your form history you may be able to see what username you typed in the gmail login form.

Answer (score 1):

That would essentially be a keystroke logger, and would need to be installed beforehand. There's no way to retroactively retrieve keystrokes.

However, when you register for a gmail account they try to have you enter a secondary email address so you can retrieve account details if necessary. If you filled this out, that account might have a notification email from account creation.